# Como puedo mostrar por pantalla con un botón si la nota media es aprobado o suspenso?

Tags: javascript

```
var notas;
var promedio;
var suma = 0;

var numeroNotas = parseInt(prompt("Escribe la cantidad de    notas a sacar promedio:"));

for(i = 0; i < numeroNotas; i++){
    var notas = parseInt(prompt("Pon la nota  " + i));
    suma = suma + notas;
}

promedio = suma / numeroNotas;

alert("El resultado es " + promedio)
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, te recomiendo leer [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado para crear lo que quieres? ¿Has probado a crear un formulario con HTML?

Comment: Comparto lo dicho por @PabloLozano... ¿donde está tu intento de hacer lo que pretendes?  No has expuesto correctamente la pregunta, pues no has incluido el aspecto de lo que quieres hacer (el HTML) ni has puesto el intento de hacerlo como pretendes en javascript. Tal com está ahora tu código ya encuentra la nota promedio, y eso está bien para avanzar en tu proyecto, pero ¿donde está el resto?  Aqui **no hacemos código a medida**, lo siento (o no deberíamos). Reléete [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor aceptada y recibas mejor ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Dejo un ejemplo completo basado en el tuyo para lo revises.

```js
let notas = [];

//calificación minima para aprobar
//cambiar según sea tu caso
const CALIFICACION_APROBACION = 5; 


function Pedirnotas(){
  let pedir = true;
  while(pedir){
    let n = prompt("Pon la nota");
    if(n != undefined) {
      n= Number(n);
      if(n){
        notas.push(n);
      }
      
      pedir = confirm("¿Desea agregar otra nota?");
    }
    else{
      pedir=false;
    }
    
  }
}

function MostrarNotas(){
  const notasDiv = document.getElementById("notasDiv");
  notasDiv.innerHTML = "";
  for(n of notas){
    notasDiv.innerHTML += `<li>${n}</li>`;
  }
}

function AlertarPromedio(){
  alert("El promedio es : " + GetPromedio());
}

function GetPromedio(){
   return GetSuma() / notas.length;
}
function GetSuma(){
  let suma=0;
  for(n of notas){
    suma+=n;
  }
  return suma;
}

function RemoverNotas(){
  const notasDiv = document.getElementById("notasDiv");
  notasDiv.innerHTML = "";
  notas=[];
}


function Alertaraprovacion(){
    if(isAprobado()){
       
       alert("El alumno ha aprobado gracias a SOes");
    }
    else{
      alert("El alumno no ha aprobado ");
    }
    
}
function isAprobado(){
   return GetPromedio() >= CALIFICACION_APROBACION;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Pedirnotas()">Pedir Notas</button>
<button onclick="MostrarNotas()">Mostrar Notas</button>
<button onclick="AlertarPromedio()">Calcular Promedio</button>
<button onclick="RemoverNotas()">Remover Todas las notas</button>
<button onclick="Alertaraprovacion()">Verifica si ha aprobado</button>
<ul id="notasDiv"></ul>
```