# Cómo mostrar por pantalla un resultado sin usar alert y no perder la demás información de la página

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo mostrar por pantalla la function *MostrarPromedio* y la function *Alertaraprovacion* (estas funciones son las que se encargan de mostrar los resultados) sin usar un alert y en caso de utilizar un `document.write` se muestre el resultado sin perder el resto de información que contiene dicha página, o si es posible, usar otra manera de mostrar el resultado por pantalla?

```
    let notas = []; 
    const CALIFICACION_APROBACION = 5; 

    function Pedirnotas(){
        let pedir = true;
        while(pedir){
            let n = prompt("Pon la nota");
            if(n != undefined) {
                n= Number(n);
                if(n){
                    notas.push(n);
                }   
                pedir = confirm("¿Desea agregar otra nota?");
            }else{
                pedir=false;
            }
        }
    }

    function MostrarNotas(){
        const notasDiv = document.getElementById("notasDiv");
        notasDiv.innerHTML = "";
        for(n of notas){
            notasDiv.innerHTML += `<li>${n}</li>`;
        }
    }

   'Esta es la funcion mencionada anteriormente en la que necesito ayuda'
    
    function MostrarPromedio(){
        document.write("El promedio es : " + GetPromedio() );
    }

    function GetPromedio(){
        return GetSuma() / notas.length;
    }

    function GetSuma(){
        let suma=0;
        for(n of notas){
            suma+=n;
        }
    return suma;
    }

    function RemoverNotas(){
        const notasDiv = document.getElementById("notasDiv");
        notasDiv.innerHTML = "";
        notas=[];
    }

    'Esta es la otra function ya mencionada'

    function Alertaraprovacion(){
        var calificacion = GetPromedio();
        if(calificacion < 5 ){
            document.write("Su calificacion es INSUFICIENTE. " ); 
        }
        if(isAprobado()){
            document.write("El alumno ha aprobado. ");
        } else{
            document.write("El alumno no ha aprobado. ");
        }
    }

    function isAprobado(){
        return GetPromedio() >= CALIFICACION_APROBACION;
    }
```

Los botones hechos a partir de código html que permiten dar los números y el resultado al pulsar un botón:

```
<button onclick = "Pedirnotas()">Pedir Notas</button>
<button onclick = "MostrarNotas()">Mostrar Notas</button>
<button onclick = "MostrarPromedio()">Calcular Promedio</button>
<button onclick = "RemoverNotas()">Remover Todas las notas</button>
<button onclick = "Alertaraprovacion()">Mostrar calificación </button>
<ul id = "notasDiv"></ul>
```

Comment: Esto es lo mismo que https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/565364/301324 ???

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a mostrar los resultados en la misma página, te aconsejo usar la misma herramienta que utilizaste para mostrar las notas: `document.getElementById()`

Puedes colocar un elemento de texto en el html para mostrar la nota.

```
<label id="txtcalificacion">Calificación: </label>
```

La id es lo que identifica al elemento en cuestión. Osea que para conseguir el elemento deberás usar `document.getElementById('txtcalificacion')`, en este caso.

Para cambiar el texto puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
document.getElementById("txtcalificacion").innerHTML = "Calificacion = "+GetPromedio();
```

Que es lo que yo hice por ejemplo.

```js
let notas = []; 
    const CALIFICACION_APROBACION = 5; 
    function MostrarPromedio(){ //esta es la parte importante
        document.getElementById("txtcalificacion").innerHTML = "Calificacion = "+GetPromedio();
    }
    function Pedirnotas(){
        let pedir = true;
        while(pedir){
            let n = prompt("Pon la nota");
            if(n != undefined) {
                n= Number(n);
                if(n){
                    notas.push(n);
                }   
                pedir = confirm("¿Desea agregar otra nota?");
            }else{
                pedir=false;
            }
        }
    }

    function MostrarNotas(){
        const notasDiv = document.getElementById("notasDiv");
        notasDiv.innerHTML = "";
        for(n of notas){
            notasDiv.innerHTML += `<li>${n}</li>`;
        }
    }
    function GetPromedio(){
        return GetSuma() / notas.length;
    }
    function Alertaraprobacion(){
        var calificacion = GetPromedio();
        if(calificacion < 5 ){
            document.write("Su calificacion es INSUFICIENTE. " ); 
        }
        if(isAprobado()){
            document.write("El alumno ha aprobado. ");
        } else{
            document.write("El alumno no ha aprobado. ");
        }
    }
    function GetSuma(){
        let suma=0;
        for(n of notas){
            suma+=n;
        }
    return suma;
    }
    function RemoverNotas(){
        const notasDiv = document.getElementById("notasDiv");
        notasDiv.innerHTML = "";
        notas=[];
    }
```

```html
<button onclick = "Pedirnotas()">Pedir Notas</button>
<button onclick = "MostrarNotas()">Mostrar Notas</button>
<button onclick = "MostrarPromedio()">Calcular Promedio</button>
<button onclick = "RemoverNotas()">Remover Todas las notas</button>
<ul id = "notasDiv"></ul>
<label id="txtcalificacion">Calificación: </label>
```

Solo hice el mostrar promedio, no entendí bien que quisiste hacer con lo de alertar aprobación pero puedes usar la misma lógica. Creo que hay unos errores en esa parte por eso te lo dejo a ti.

También ten en cuenta que puedes usar otros elementos de HTML, te aconsejo investigarlos y ver cuales pueden quedar mejor, no es necesario usar